# URL Parameter (&cfs=1) Causing .NET Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I recently added a bunch of open graph tags to my site and now I'm getting .NET exceptions related to requests for these images.  Specifically,  it looks like some social site (likely Facebook [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032484/facebook-timeline-wallpost-image-cropped-after-like)) is requesting the images but appending "&cfs=1" to the end of the image URL:

http://www.cheatsheetwarroom.com/images/socialsharing/rankings/running-back-rankings.jpg&cfs=1

.NET doesn't take kindly to the "?" character in the URL and delivers the following exception:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

I'm assuming this is probably causing a problem when someone is sharing my content, so is there a way to avoid the exception without sacrificing security?

Comment: wat? .NET is perfectly fine with regular query-strings. Are you sure there isn't perhaps some POST/form data that looks a little dodgy?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the sample URL.  The character after the image extension is an ampersand, not a question mark.  I think that's the problem.

Comment: You could catch the exception, clean up the URL, and continue ... ?

Comment: How could you do this?  This exception is generated very early in the pipeline.

Comment: @bperniciaro: Did you find a permanent solution to that problem? Having the same one here...

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to find a solid solution to this problem, a damn shame too.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, suspected that the error was thrown too far up the pipeline for me to do anything about it, but I gave it a go anyway and came up with this UrlRewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Remove ampersand in JPG file extention" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="([\w/]+.jpg)(&amp;[a-z=0-9]+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

...I'd prefer to do a permanent redirect but UrlRewrite wouldn't use {R:1} for the 301, so rewrite is the best we can do with the rule in this format.

Comment: I tried this approach and while I no longer get a "potentially dangerous request", I do get a 404 error page